# Can't umount mnt/sys after mounting it with --bind for chroot

Tags: mount, chroot

I'm working with an ext4 image file that boots into a VM. To set it up I do a chroot of it:

```
sudo mount <path>/image.ext4 mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc mnt/proc
sudo chroot mnt
```

Then I did some python checking, by running the interpreter `python3` and quit:

```
exit
sudo umount mnt/dev
sudo umount mnt/proc
sudo umount mnt/sys
```

And this last command fails, and so I cant `umount mnt`

/mnt/sys: target is busy.

I can't find what is using it. I've tried lsof and df and can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about what could be reading files there I found the culprit: vscode Remote-ssh plugin. Because I had a folder levels above mnt open on vscode, it was crawling indefinitely through all the files, and for some reason it never stopped reading things in `mnt/sys`, which is why it was always busy.

Solved this by killing the processes. In vscode there's an option to "Kill VS code server on host", then added `**/mnt/**` to the excluded paths.